# JavaScript - comparing two same strings but they are not equal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angularjs `$http` to send a request, for basic authorization I provided headers with `'Authorization': this.basicAuthorization`

But it doesn't work, I found out that there is a problem in `this.basicAuthorization`. When I replace it with a string `'Basic SOME_BASE64_ENCODED_STRING'`

```
this.basicAuthorization = 'Basic'+' '+ btoa('username'+';'+'password');
this.myString = 'Basic SOME_BASE64_ENCODED_STRING';

console.log(this.basicAuthorization + " " + typeof this.basicAuthorization + " lenght " + this.basicAuthorization.length);
console.log(this.myString + " " + typeof this.myString + " length " + this.myString.length);


if(this.basicAuthorization == this.myString){
    console.log("equal")
}
else{
    console.log('not equal');
    console.log(this.basicAuthorization + " " + typeof this.basicAuthorization + " lenght " + this.basicAuthorization.length);
    console.log(this.myString + " " + typeof this.myString + " length " + this.myString.length);

}
```

And what I see in a console is

> not equal
>
> Basic SOME_BASE64_ENCODED_STRING string 82
>
> Basic SOME_BASE64_ENCODED_STRING string 82

Why are the strings are not equal and why when I use btoa() also my http request is not working and when I provide it with `this.myString` it works

Comment: side note: `lenght` spelled wrong in first `console.log`..it should be `length`

Comment: If JS states they are not equal - they are not equal. There is no reason to not trust JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
this.basicAuthorization = 'Basic'+' '+ btoa('username'+';'+'password');
```

To:

```
this.basicAuthorization = 'Basic'+' '+ btoa('username'+':'+'password');
```

In basic authentication the username and password must be seperated by `:`. [See the HTTP Authentication RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt).